# Show true or false for a specific combination of 3 cells

Tags: excel, countif

[image]I have 3 columns that I need to reference in an excel formula. I need to make a formula that will show Yes or No if (C=1, D=yes, E=No OR C=1, D=No, E=Yes)
Here is what I tried so far however Excel is not liking it.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(c2,"1",d2,"Yes",e2,"No")OR(IF(COUNTIFS(c2,"1",d2,"No",e2,"Yes"),"Yes","No)
```

Comment: Mind the sharing the exact word (error msg) Excel say disliking it ? (or sreenshot of it..)

Comment: `=IF(OR(COUNTIFS(c2,"1",d2,"Yes",e2,"No"),COUNTIFS(c2,"1",d2,"No",e2,"Yes")),"Yes","No)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, try:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C2:E2 = {1,"yes","no"}),AND(C2:E2 = {1,"no","yes"})),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work I am getting #value

Comment: Works here. Try confirming with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: I think we are on the right track with the exception that only C will = 1 D and E will never have that value. D and E can only have "Yes" or "No"

Comment: @ThisGuyUsesPowershell I don't understand the point you are trying to make. Please  provide an example of a wrong output for a given set of values in `C:E`